# If post ID has_term?

Tags: php

I'm trying to find out whether the post `has_term` by post ID or not.

Right now I have this:

```
<?php $postid = $_GET['post_id'];
if( has_term( 'campaign', 'type' ) ): ?>
//Do something
<?php endif; ?>
```

How do I incorporate $postid variable inside the `has_term`?

So that I could check only that specific post id.

I have tried:

```
    <?php $postid = $_GET['post_id']; 
    if( has_term($postid, 'campaign', 'type' ) ): ?>
```

The above doesn't work.

Need help, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3rd parameter of `has_term()` accepts a WP_Post or Post ID. [Docs on `has_term()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/). In your example code, it would look like this:

```
<?php $postid = $_GET['post_id'];
if( has_term( 'campaign', 'type', $postid ) ): ?>
//Do something
<?php endif; ?>
```

Where `campaign` would be the term, `type` would be the taxonomy, and `$postid` is the post that may have the `campaign` term.

Comment: Brilliant! I thought I was missing something very small :) Thanks a lot for your help!